# How to get a string response from a triton server in a multi model endpoint in aws sagemaker?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nvidia, amazon-sagemaker

I have a multi model endpoint set up in sagemaker utilizing nvidia triton . sample code below

- model.py and config.pbtxt for python backend. I have set the input type to int and output to string in config file and in the model.py file , inside execute function , I pass the tokenized input for the text, that i want to summarize using distilbart (https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/distilbert) model. based on the documentation , execute function returns a list of  pb_utils.InferenceResponse. is it possible to return string from this function. if yes, can someone point to me an example?

model.py

```
import numpy as np
import sys
import os
import json
from pathlib import Path

import torch

import triton_python_backend_utils as pb_utils

class TritonPythonModel:

    def initialize(self, args):
       ....
       

    def execute(self, requests):
        responses = []
        for request in requests:
            input_ids = pb_utils.get_input_tensor_by_name(request, "input_ids")
            input_ids = input_ids.as_numpy()
            input_ids = torch.as_tensor(input_ids).long().cuda()

            inputs = {'input_ids': input_ids}
            translation = self.model.generate(**inputs, num_beams=1)

       
            inference_response = pb_utils.InferenceResponse(
                output_tensors=[
                    pb_utils.Tensor(
                        "output",
                        ....
                    )
                ]
            )
            responses.append(inference_response)
        return responses
```

config.pbtxt

```
name: 'somename'
backend: 'python'
max_batch_size: 16
input [{
  name: "INPUT"
  data_type: TYPE_INT32
  dims: [ -1 ]}
]
output[{
   name: "OUTPUT"
   data_type: TYPE_STRING
   ...
}]
```